# ASP.Net MVC: Redirect to custom URI Scheme is not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, redirect

When I try to redirect to custom URI Scheme like: `openURL://`, the web browser directs me to a relative path: `http://localhost/myServer/Main/openURL` instead of displaying `openURL://`.

My code:

```
public class MainController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult MyAction()
    {
        return Redirect("openURL://");
    }
}
```

I also used :

```
public class MainController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult MyAction()
    {
        return new RedirectResult("openURL://");
    }
}
```

but it did not work.

Answer (score 1):

Provide a fully qualified URL :-

Instead of

```
return Redirect("www.google.com");
```

Use

```
return Redirect("http://www.google.com");
```

**Edit :-** As per your updated question,
check these stackoverflow posts [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18552760/how-to-generate-a-url-for-asp-net-mvc-action-including-hostname-and-port) , [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21161097/redirect-to-external-url-with-custom-schema) , [3.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2005367/getting-full-url-of-action-in-asp-net-mvc)

Comment: This works for (www.google.com) but it is not working for custom URLs. I have a custom URL (OpenURL:) instead of (www.google.com)

Comment: @Ala...not able to understand what do you mean by custom url..as per your question this answer will work for all external url's.